# Is there a point to interacting with Pokemon in your lobby/city area?

Tags: pokemon-rumble-world

When walking up to Pokemon in the area outside the castle, they give a message bubble with a neutral face.  It looks kinda like `'_'`  If I push A next to them, they will perform an animation and their message bubble will change to a happy face.  There was also one time where the interaction ended with a happy face with hearts for eyes, though I don't remember which Pokemon were interacting.

Does this do anything?  It seems that every time I come back to this area, all the statuses are reset to that neutral face.

Answer (score 2):

If you continue to interact with a Pokemon (talking and jumping) you will increase its "affection" for you, ending with an happy face with hearts for eyes `♥_♥`, as you wrote.
You can see the exact moment when this happens, that will trigger your Mii who runs towards you with orange blinking lines around his head.

If you speak to the Pokemon again sometimes he will start to follow you for a while. After that the Pokemon will become "offended" showing a face like `u_u`.

I don't know what this means. I've tried to start a mission with a Pokemon following me, but nothing happened.